# Activity transition in Alert Dialog Builder

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have an `AlertDialog`. I am unable to get the slide in and slide out activity transition.

The Java code is as below. I am getting an error after start activity. Can anyone help how to add activity transition for these?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    public void select2Button12b(View v) {

        dialogBuildmea112 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final String[] strSizee = {  "\nUnit 1\n\nClassification \n", "\nUnit 2\n\nComplete works \n" };

        dialogBuildmea112.setTitle("Select unit:");
        dialogBuildmea112.setSingleChoiceItems(strSizee, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichaaede1) {

                switch(whichaaede1) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(Worksa.this, Worksa.class);
                        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right,
                                R.anim.left);
                        startActivity(i1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent j1 = new Intent(Worksa.this, W1.class);
                        startActivity(j1);
                        this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right,
                                R.anim.left);

                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        AlertDialog nopb1 =  dialogBuildmea112.create();            
        nopb1.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: show error (from logcat)

Comment: prolly you are getting compile time error which says somthing obvious like `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` has no method `overridePendingTransition` ... please learn java's basics

Comment: Actually, the problem is that the activity transition is not happening. Activities are switched without any transition. How to solve this?

Comment: Try `YourclassName.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right,
                            R.anim.left);`

Comment: overridePendingTransition goes after startActivity (for case 0:) and do as Rethinavel Pillai says... you're out of the scope of your Activity

Comment: Thank you Rethinavel. It works well.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust order and change this:

```
public void select2Button12b(View v)
{


    dialogBuildmea112 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final String[] strSizee = {  "\nUnit 1\n\nClassification \n", "\nUnit 2\n\nComplete works \n"};


    dialogBuildmea112.setTitle("Select unit:");
    dialogBuildmea112.setSingleChoiceItems(strSizee, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichaaede1) {


             switch(whichaaede1){
             case 0:
                 Intent i1 = new Intent(Worksa.this, Worksa.class);

                    startActivity(i1);
         Activity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right,
                            R.anim.left);

                    break;
             case 1:
                 Intent j1 = new Intent(Worksa.this, W1.class);
                    startActivity(j1);
                     Activity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right,
                            R.anim.left);

                    break;

             }


        }


    });


     AlertDialog nopb1 =  dialogBuildmea112.create();


        nopb1.show();


}
```